# ruby watir selecting text with &raquo aka double right angle quote

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a link that I am trying to select using ruby watir that once the link is selected, It then puts a small >> double right angle quote next to the link. I believe this is also know as "&raquo" I can select the link the first time when it does not have this &raquo but once the link is selected and the >> is now present at the end of the text in the link. I am having trouble selecting it a second time.

```
div style="float: right;">
<a title="View Jobs" href="/media/jobs">View Jobs »</a>
<br>
</div>
```

This is my watir selection before the >> are present on the link

```
browser.frame(:id, "left").link(:text, "Virtual Tapes").when_present.click
```

I have tried adding the &raquo to my code ( below)

```
browser.frame(:id, "left").link(:text, "Virtual Tapes &raquo").when_present.click
```

But it still doesn't select the link the second time once the >> is present on the link. *Note I am adding a semicolon ; to the &raquo in my code example above but this input box is actually making the double right angle quote (»)
Any suggestions? the .frame is present in the code due to the page having left and right hand frames

Comment: is there any way you can add id's to your <a> tags? This would allow you to use something other than the obviously brittle text value. In addition, not knowing how your ruby program is structured, you could save a reference to that link which should work as long as you stay on the same page and that element stays in the same DOM location. my_link = browser.frame(:id, "left").link(:text, "Virtual Tapes").when_present // my_link.click // >> added // my_link.click

Comment: Is the link text "View Jobs »" or "Virtual Tapes »"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that the double right angles to the text you are locating:

```
browser.frame(:id, "left").link(:text, "Virtual Tapes »").when_present.click
```

Note that because this is a UTF-8 character, you may get a `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` error. If you do, you will want to add the following comment at the very start of your file to specify it as being encoded in UTF-8:

```
#encoding: UTF-8
```

If you do not want to stick in UTF-8 characters, you could also use a regular expression to locate the link by just the plain text part:

```
browser.frame(:id, "left").link(:text, /^Virtual Tapes/).when_present.click
```

Comment: Thanks I am using the regular expression to grab the value. That works and I had tried to use the >> in my text I was locating and it did not like that. I guess I will stick with the regular expression method. Thanks